# Extra space added on reverse string function

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a string using Python without using the `[::-1]` solution.

My code seems to work fine for several test cases, but it adds an extra space for one instance and I can't figure out why.

```
def reverse(s):
    r = list(s)
    start, end = 0, len(s) - 1
    x = end//2
    for i in range(x):
        r[start], r[end] = r[end], r[start]
        start += 1
        end -= 1

    print(''.join(r))


reverse('A man, a plan, a canal: Panama')

# returns 'amanaP :lanac  a,nalp a ,nam A'
# note the double space ^^ - don't know why


reverse('a monkey named fred, had a banana')

# 'returns ananab a dah ,derf deman yeknom a'


reverse('Able was I ere I saw Elba')

# returns 'ablE was I ere I saw elbA'
```

Comment: I notice that `reverse('abcd')` prints `dbca` instead of `dcba`. Is that intentional? If not, I suspect the root cause is the same as your double space problem.

Comment: Id imagine it has to do with even/odd characters.  I didn't count, but I bet that the one where there is a double space contains an odd number of characters.

Comment: there is also `''.join(reversed('this method'))` - but you probably do not want that either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    x = end//2
```

to

```
    x = len(s)//2
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug appears to be related to the handling of even-length strings. A much easier way to build a string reverse function would be:

```
def reverse(s):
    result = ""
    for character in reversed(s):  #Reversed returns an object that, when used in a for loop, outputs each object of a string, list, or other iterable, in reverse order.
        result += character #Add that character back to the result.
    return result
```

This function works regardless of string length. I hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like the goal is to avoid using built-in reverse methods. If you're going to use `reversed`, why not just return that?

Comment: Or just : 
`def reverse(s):
    return ''.join(reversed(s))`

(but I agree with  Mark Meyer)

Comment: @Mark Meyer reversed(i) is a generator, not a directly reversed version of the value. As such, to get the value itself, you need to use a for loop to build the results from the generator back into a string.

Comment: @CrazySqueak -- `return ''.join(reversed(s))`

Answer (score 1):

Using the technique you're using it's probably clearer to test `start` agains `end` directly rather than trying to manage lengths and indexes. You can do that with `while start < end:`. For example:

```
def reverse(s):
    r = list(s)
    start, end = 0, len(s) - 1
    while start < end:
        r[start], r[end] = r[end], r[start]
        start += 1
        end -= 1

    print(''.join(r))

reverse('A man, a plan, a canal: Panama')
```

**prints**

```
amanaP :lanac a ,nalp a ,nam A
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is in the boundary condition for an even-length string:

```
start, end = 0, len(s) - 1
x = end//2
for i in range(x):
```

For instance, with 8 characters, your `for` iterator is (range(3)), which gets you only the first three positions.

You fail to swap the middle pair.

The "clean" way to fix this is to change your `x` calculation:

```
x = (end+1) // 2
```

or, as others have said

```
x = len(s) // 2
```